# Migrate a go repository from Bitbucket to Gitlab

Tags: git, go, gitlab, bitbucket

I have a go repository and several dependency repositories I recently moved from BitBucket to GitLab. The latest version works as the dependencies have been updated, but the older versions are still pointing to bitbucket where the repo no longer exists. Is there anyway for me to fix the git history to point to the new location other than updating every commit? I would like to save the history because there are several major releases.

Comment: That sounds like _rewriting history_ to me. https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Comment: The proper solution would be to keep at least the old versions on Bitbucket as well. At least for a while. Or possibly a redirect from BitBucket to GitLab (if BitBucket supports it).

Comment: I think this link can help you! https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase